# SQL query for a database scheme

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server how do you query a database to bring back all the tables that have a field of a specific name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following query will bring back a unique list of tables where `Column_Name` is equal to the column you are looking for:

```
SELECT Table_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE Column_Name = 'Desired_Column_Name'
GROUP BY Table_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table_Name
FROM Information_Schema.Columns
WHERE Column_Name = 'YourFieldName'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm old-school:

```
SELECT DISTINCT object_name(id)
FROM syscolumns
WHERE name = 'FIELDNAME'
```